# Using context:component-scan to scan all base-package

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As far as I know, `context:component-scan` requires the `base-package` attribute to be specified. How do I configure this to scan all the classes in the classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. That would be a nightmare.

For example, this would mean that all classes of all your libs are loaded, turning all your optional dependencies into required ones. I.e., if you had spring-orm.jar on the class path, this would require you to have all of Hibernate, JPA, JDO and MyBatis on the class path.

Packages are an important part of designing an application. If you don't have one root package, you can scan several. But if it's not possible for you to identify all root packages you need, then you have serious organizational problems, and you shouldn't expect Spring to fix them for you.